# GDAL missing VFK driver

Tags: python, gdal, sqlite

I've installed gdal v3.6.0 with conda v4.12.0, but I'm missing VFK vector driver. How can I add it?

When I run a siple script:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

vfk_file = '727008.vfk'

ds = gdal.Open(vfk_file, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

if ds is None:
    print('Unable to open VFK data file')
else:
    print('VFK data file opened successfully')

ds = None
```

This error occurs:

```bash
(geodata) PS C:\Users\MainUser\Dev\python\gdal_test> python .\test.py
ERROR 4: `727008.vfk' not recognized as a supported file format.
Unable to open VFK data file
```

And when I list all drivers, the VFK one is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFK is a vector driver. You need to import ogr instead of gdal `from osgeo import ogr` and use ogr.Open

`ogr.Open("727008.vfk`")

You can test if you have the VFK driver with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo --format VFK
Format Details:
  Short Name: VFK
  Long Name: Czech Cadastral Exchange Data Format
  Supports: Vector
  Extension: vfk
  Help Topic: drivers/vector/vfk.html
  Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.
<OpenOptionList>
  <Option name="SUPPRESS_GEOMETRY" type="boolean" description="whether to suppress geometry" default="NO" />
  <Option name="FILE_FIELD" type="boolean" description="whether to include VFK filename field" default="NO" />
</OpenOptionList>
```